# .htaccess redirect if IP address or user credentials do not match

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

This is my current .htaccess file. It restricts access to a directory if either the IP address or user credentials don't match.

I would like to know how to redirect unauthorised users to another website (not file) e.g. www.google.com if they enter the wrong username/password or are not from the allowed IP address.

I have attempted to add a 401 redirect e.g. **ErrorDocument 401 www.google.com** but this doesn't appear to work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Define IP Address
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^123\.123\.123\.1$" IsIntern

# Authentication
AuthUserFile /.htpasswds/public_html/home/passwd
AuthName "Website Protected"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=IsIntern
satisfy any
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use full URL in 401 custom handler. Apache will throw this error in the logs:

```
cannot use a full URL in a 401 ErrorDocument directive --- ignoring!
```

Instead you can do:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /handle401.html
```

And from `handle401.html` you can redirect to any other website using Javascript.